# setting background-image in jquery is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using following code to show image on document load using jquery.
But is is not showing the image.
My code is

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
      $('#cover-img').css("background-image", "http://webneel.com/wallpaper/sites/default/files/images/04-2013/island-beach-scenery-wallpaper.jpg");
  });
```

```css
.default_cover_image {
    position: relative;
    width: 1350px;
    height: 320px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #b8dcf4;
  }
```

```html
<div class="default_cover_image" id="cover-img"></div>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xrcwrn/19dd7nwa/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add `url()`:

```
$('#cover-img').css(
  "background-image", "url('http://webneel.com/wallpaper/sites/default/files/images/04-2013/island-beach-scenery-wallpaper.jpg')"
  //-------------------^^^^^
);
```

The syntax is:

```
background-image: url('path');
```

But you have given:

```
background-image: path;
```

**Snippet**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
      $('#cover-img').css("url('background-image", "http://webneel.com/wallpaper/sites/default/files/images/04-2013/island-beach-scenery-wallpaper.jpg')");
  });
```

```css
.default_cover_image {
    position: relative;
    width: 1350px;
    height: 320px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #b8dcf4;
  }
```

```html
<div class="default_cover_image" id="cover-img"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
$('#cover-img').css("background-image", "url('http://webneel.com/wallpaper/sites/default/files/images/04-2013/island-beach-scenery-wallpaper.jpg')");
```

Answer (score 1):

you could give a custom class with background image and later on document load you could the class to desired element.

try this http://jsfiddle.net/19dd7nwa/3/

```
 .customclass {
          background-image:url("http://webneel.com/wallpaper/sites/default/files/images/04-2013/island-beach-scenery-wallpaper.jpg");
     }



 $(document).ready(function () {
  $('#cover-img').addClass('customclass');
 });
```